# python calling classes dynamically

Tags: python, python-2.7, getattr

I want to call python classes dynamically,

These are the classes that I want to call

```
class AutosoukModelMakeFuzzyComparisonModule:
    def __init__(self,configurationLoader=None, moduleConfigurationFile=None, settings=None):
        pass
```

and

```
class DefaultFuzzyComparisonModule:
    def __init__(self,configurationLoader, moduleConfigurationFile, settings = None):
        pass
```

and these too classes located in **fuzzymodules** folder

and I call them from ** FuzzyComparisonPipeline.py** which is in the same directory as **fuzzymodules** like this:

```
for module in FuzzyComparisonPipeline.fuzzyModules:
        name = module['name']
        configurationLoader = module['configurationLoader']
        moduleConfigurationFile = module['moduleConfigurationFile']
        settings = module['settings']
        module_to_import = __import__('fuzzymodules.'+name)
        instanceOfModule = getattr(module_to_import, name).__init__(configurationLoader, moduleConfigurationFile, settings)
        #instanceOfModule(configurationLoader, moduleConfigurationFile, settings)
    return item
```

I got this error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "path to my FuzzyComparisonPipeline.py", line 9, in process_item
    instanceOfModule = getattr(module_to_import, name).__init__(configurationLoader, moduleConfigurationFile, settings)
TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

and my question is how the **init**() takes 2 arguments, as you see, in both classes the **init** takes three arguments

Could you help please

**i can't give you the whole code, because it is so complicated, everything else is working fine, i am sure of that, my problem is in calling that function.**

the values of the **for** loop coming from this xml

```
<FuzzyComparison>
    <Modules>
        <Module>
            <name>AutosoukModelMakeFuzzyComparisonModule</name>
            <configurationLoader>DefaultLoader</configurationLoader>
            <configurationFile>MakesModels.conf</configurationFile>
            <settings></settings>
        </Module>
        <Module>
            <name>DefaultFuzzyComparisonModule</name>
            <configurationLoader>DefaultLoader</configurationLoader>
            <configurationFile>Buildings.conf</configurationFile>
            <settings>
                <attribute>building</attribute>
                <second>2222duxk fuck fuck</second>
            </settings>
        </Module>
    </Modules>
    </FuzzyComparison>
```

Comment: You'd not call `__init__` directly, you'd call the object itself (just remove the `.__init__` part). But clearly you are not getting the right code here as you are trying to instantiate that doesn't take 3 arguments. If you gave us an *actual* traceback we might be able to be of more help.

Comment: what is `name` in your example? Which `.py` file does it lie in, what is the directory structure for that `.py` file? Also, 1. `__init__()` in your examples take 4 arguments (the first being the object itself) . 2. `__init__()` is not used for object creation, its used for object initialization , but seems like you want to use it for object creation (but it should not be used like that) .

Comment: @MartijnPieters I will update the question

Comment: @AnandSKumar I will update the question and add more context

Comment: @MartijnPieters i tried my best to give you the whole picture

Comment: @AnandSKumar i tried my best to give you the whole picture, question updated now

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: so what does `print(getattr(module_to_import, name))` tell you is being imported?

Comment: @MartijnPieters i tells me this: <module 'fuzzymodules.AutosoukModelMakeFuzzyComparisonModule' from 'path to my fuzzymodules/AutosoukModelMakeFuzzyComparisonModule.pyc'>

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: so you don't have the class, you have a module object. You'll need to do another `getattr()` on that module.

Comment: @MartijnPieters do you mean that i should remove the __init__ from `instanceOfModule` and then do something like `classCall = getattr(instaceOfModue).__init__(here are the arguments)` ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: you need to remove the `__init__` call *too*, but your method of retrieving the class is flawed. Fix that first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are retrieving a *module*, not the class in the module; the `__import__()` function returns the top-level package, not the nested module itself.

You really want to use [`importlib.import_module()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) instead here, it behaves as you expect.

Next, you want to call the class object thus retrieved, not the `__init__` method directly. Let *Python* call that for you, it'll do so to initialise the instance you create by calling the class:

```
from importlib import import_module

for module in FuzzyComparisonPipeline.fuzzyModules:
    name = module['name']
    configurationLoader = module['configurationLoader']
    moduleConfigurationFile = module['moduleConfigurationFile']
    settings = module['settings']
    module_to_import = import_module('fuzzymodules.' + name)
    instance = getattr(module_to_import, name)(configurationLoader, moduleConfigurationFile, settings)
```

Comment: and pleas last question, now i have an instance of the class, right? so lets say that i can do something like : `instance.myFunction()` ?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli: yes, you have an instance of the class, so you can call methods on it.

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation of `__import__()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) -

> **__import__(name[, globals[, locals[, fromlist[, level]]]])**
>
> When the name variable is of the form package.module, normally, **the top-level package (the name up till the first dot) is returned**, not the module named by name. However, when a non-empty fromlist argument is given, the module named by name is returned.

(Emphasis mine)

So in your case, the module - `fuzzymodules` is being returned - not the module containing your class.

You should specify the `fromlist` argument as `name` . Example -

```
module_to_import = __import__('fuzzymodules.'+name, fromlist=name)
```

---

Also , another issue is that you should not directly call the `__init__()` function of the class to create an object for it, instead call it directly, Example -

```
instanceOfModule = getattr(module_to_import, name)(configurationLoader, moduleConfigurationFile, settings)
```

`__init__()` function is called for initialization after the object has been created.

Comment: I really appreciate the efforts, but  `Martijn Pieters` has been helping me from the beginning, i must accept his answer (if he writes one), plus one for your efforts, I wish i could accept both of your answers